# How to use AVAudioplayer plyer impementation without leak

Tags: iphone, memory-leaks, core-audio, avaudioplayer

hi made application in which i used avaudioplayer for playing background sound. but i get leak in my project when first time sounds come. can any one guide me how to implement avaudioplayer without leak.

Comment: post code and we can help you figure out where you went wrong.

Comment: Please read this: http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx